# I am trying to install Perforce P4 on my Mac and do not know where to park the binary

Tags: macos, perforce

I downloaded the binary for Perforce P4 command line tool and made it executable. However i am not sure where I should place the binary. I have seen suggestions of /usr/bin - /usr/local/bin - or /usr/local/lib - or anywhere that is on my $PATH - but just not sure where the correct location is.

I like to keep my files organized but i just don't work often enough in the terminal to intuitively know where it should go and this is first time i am looking to use Perforce from the command line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`/usr/local/bin` is a pretty standard place to park CLI binaries.